# How to allow portion of the page load at the very last?

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I working in application development using `ASP.NET` in `C#.`

I have a `Grid View` which I wanted it to load at the very last of the page load.

The page should load the master page first, where all images and other functionality was loaded, then only load the `GridView`.

Can this achieve on c# back end code?like the page life cycle event.

Please advice, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Have a look at the page life-cycle **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events**

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell to load something first or last using C#, because it is about HTTP Request and Response which is basically TCP/IP. You can however use AJAX to load some of the contents first and load some other contents last handling Javascript events like `onload`.

**EDIT**

I understand loading in this context as loading the page on the client side. If you are talking about loading page on the server side, yes you can do that. You need to load contents using page lifecycle events.

Comment: thank you for your reply, let say I wanted to load on server side, the last loading event in page lifecycle is it Page_PreRender?

Comment: Yes, after PreRender you cannot change the contents of the page.